# Get SQL stored procedure output parameters via query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here I have a sql script which retrieves all stored procedures and it's parameters.

```
select * 
from sys.parameters 
inner join sys.procedures on parameters.object_id = procedures.object_id 
inner join sys.types on parameters.system_type_id = types.system_type_id 
                     and parameters.user_type_id = types.user_type_id
--where procedures.name = 'STORED_PROC_NAME'
```

What I want to do is to be able to grab the stored procedures output parameters this way if at all possible.

If someone could point me to where in the `sys` catalog views I can find this information, it would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column `is_output` in `sys.parameters` is 1, when it is an output parameter.

> ```
> is_output     bit     1 = Parameter is OUTPUT or RETURN; otherwise, 0.
> ```
>
> From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-parameters-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

So change your query to:

```
select *
       from sys.parameters 
            inner join sys.procedures
                       on parameters.object_id = procedures.object_id 
            inner join sys.types
                       on parameters.system_type_id = types.system_type_id
                       and parameters.user_type_id = types.user_type_id
       where parameters.is_output = 1;
```

Comment: Ah! So simple and it was right there in front of me :p

Thanks! Issue resolved.

Comment: @user2292759 Perhaps you can accept the reply as the answer?